# "Chord method" Result is displayed in the Label

Tags: ios, xcode, math, swift4

I have code so that when I click "=" to find a solution using the "Chord method"

How can I make it so that the result is displayed in the Label how in **Console**??

[image: Console]

[image: Results]

```
var resultsArray = [AnyObject]()
var a: Float = 0.0
var b: Float = 0.0
var xNext: Float = 0
var nextFunc: Float = 3
var funcB: Float = 0
var iter: Int = 0
var result = ""

@IBOutlet weak var aInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bInput: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
resultsArray.removeAll()
    iter = 0
    a = Float(aInput.text!)!
    b = Float(bInput.text!)!
    funcB = pow(b, 3)-b-1
    nextFunc = pow(a, 3)-a-1
    xNext = a
    while (-0.001..<0.001).contains(nextFunc) != true{
        xNext = xNext - ((b - xNext)/(funcB - nextFunc)) * nextFunc
        nextFunc = pow(xNext, 3) - xNext - 1
        iter+=1
        resultLabel.text = "x\(iter) = \(xNext) \nF(x\(iter)) = \(nextFunc)\n"
        print ("x\(iter) = \(xNext) \nF(x\(iter)) = \(nextFunc)\n")
        resultsArray.append(resultLabel as AnyObject)
    }
    view.endEditing (true)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an `UILabel` is a reference type object, your code is not adding new labels to the array, it's simply adding the same label over and over (and overriding it's text).

Since I assume you want to add the results to your `UITableView`, you first need to change `resultsArray` to be a `[String]()` instead of a `[AnyObject]()`.

Then you can adapt

```
    resultLabel.text = "x\(iter) = \(xNext) \nF(x\(iter)) = \(nextFunc)\n"
    print ("x\(iter) = \(xNext) \nF(x\(iter)) = \(nextFunc)\n")
    resultsArray.append(resultLabel as AnyObject)
```

to

```
    let result = "x\(iter) = \(xNext) \nF(x\(iter)) = \(nextFunc)\n"
    resultsArray.append(result)
    tableView.reloadData()
```

Now, the final step is to make your `tableView` conform to it's delegates and add the delegate methods. For simplicity this uses the default iOS TableViewCell, but you can adapt it to your custom cell if you want.

Add this code somewhere at your `viewDidLoad()`

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

And add the following delegates (remember to change MyViewController to your ViewController's name)

```
extension MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return resultsArray.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let reuseIdentifier = "cellId"
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        cell.textLabel?.text = resultsArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I have only x(n) displayed in the table and I need  x(n) + F (x(n)) as in the console

Comment: You can add the results of F(x(n)) to another array, change the TableViewCellStyle to `.subtitle` and then assign the result of F(x(n)) to `cell.detailTextLabel?.text`